# FCM message not receiving when the app is closed, even I don't have notification payload

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-push-notification

FCM message not receiving when the app is closed, even I don't have notification payload. I tried a lot of solutions but not worked. Can someone help me in this issue? It is working well when the app is running, also working when the app is minimised. But not working when the app is terminated.

This is body

```
data class MessageBody(
    val to: String = "",
    val data: Data? = null
)
```

This is data

```
data class Data(
    val status: String = "",
    val uid: String = "",
    val senderName: String = "",
    val senderEmail: String = "",
    val senderUid: String = ""
)
```

This is my onMessageReceived method

```
override fun onMessageReceived(message: RemoteMessage) {
    super.onMessageReceived(message)

    val data = message.data

    when (data["status"]) {
        "ringing" -> {
            val uid = data["uid"]
            val senderName = data["senderName"]
            val senderEmail = data["senderEmail"]
            val senderUid = data["senderUid"]
            if (uid == SessionManager.getInstance(applicationContext).uid) {
                val i = Intent(applicationContext, IncomingCallActivity::class.java)
                i.putExtra("uid", senderUid)
                i.putExtra("email", senderEmail)
                i.putExtra("name", senderName)
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
                startActivity(i)
            }
        }
        "accepted" -> {
            val i = Intent("ON_CALL_ACTION")
            i.putExtra("call_status", "accepted")
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext).sendBroadcast(i)
        }
        "rejected" -> {
            val i = Intent("ON_CALL_ACTION")
            i.putExtra("call_status", "rejected")
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext).sendBroadcast(i)
        }
        "hangup" -> {
            val i = Intent("ON_CALL_ACTION")
            i.putExtra("call_status", "hangup")
            LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(applicationContext).sendBroadcast(i)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you share what solutions did you try? Have you tried setting the priority to `high`? Are you experiencing this in a specific Android version or phone model?

Comment: I already fixed it. thank you